# Rewrite url search results and pagination

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi guys im try do make a search results url with mod rewrite

my url is this

```
products/?categorie=2&subcategorie=&make=&p=2  (P is Page)
```

i tried this

```
RewriteRule ^products([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /? categorie=$1&subcategorie=$2&make=$3&p=$4 [L]
```

on this the pagination dont works

my htaccess looks this

```
RewriteEngine On
# =========== Configuracoes Default =========== #
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(css|js|xml|swf|pdf|doc|rtf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(ttf|otf|woff|eot|svg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/php/acoes.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !apple-touch-icon.png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !robots.txt

RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?([0-9]*)\/?$ php/index.php
#RewriteRule ^products([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /? categorie=$1&subcategorie=$2&make=$3&p=$4 [L]
```

My php files are inside a folder name php

My php file for return the search results is this

```
<?php
$Subcategorie_Id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["subcategorie"]);
$Categorie_Id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["categorie"]);
$Make_Id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["make"]);

$SqlCount = "SELECT Product_Id FROM tabproducts WHERE Product_Status =1";
if($Categorie_Id) $SqlCount .= " AND tabproducts.Categorie_Id = '$Categorie_Id' ";
if($Subcategorie_Id) $SqlCount .= " AND tabproducts.Subcategorie_Id = '$Subcategorie_Id' ";
if($Make_Id) $SqlCount .= " AND tabproduct.Make_Id = '$Make_Id' ";
$QueryCount = mysql_query($SqlCount, $Conn) or die(mysql_error($Conn));
$RsCount = mysql_fetch_array($QueryCount);
$recordCount = mysql_num_rows($QueryCount);
if (!$_REQUEST["p"]) $p = 1;
else $p = $_REQUEST["p"];
$pageSize = 24;
$itemIni = ($pageSize*$p)-$pageSize;
$totalPage = ceil($recordCount/$pageSize);  
?>
```

Comment: what is exactly your question sir?

Comment: hi @tradyblix i want to know how exatly i need to rewrite the search url, the url i tried dont works.

Comment: My result for your url looks slightly different on [ModRewriteGenerator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)    Result: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) $ /?categorie=$1&subcategorie=$2&make=$3&p=$4 [L]`. Not sure if the omitted products will not work for you.

Comment: Hi @MarioWenig the omitted products can be used as a prefix, but your url is the same, just dont have the prefix

Comment: @AlvaroLouzada: Yeah I figured it really doesn't make a difference, since they are the same :/ Sorry!

Comment: @tradyblix lol what he said